# I need to increase the decimal level of the audio buffer created using AVAudioPCMBuffer

Tags: swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

I have generated sounds of different frequencies, but I need to increase the decibel of the sound.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class AVTonePlayerUnit: AVAudioPlayerNode {
    let bufferCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount = 512
    let sampleRate: Double = 44_100.0
    
    var frequency: Double = 440.0
    var amplitude: Double = 0.25
    
    private var theta: Double = 0.0
    private var audioFormat: AVAudioFormat!
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: sampleRate, channels: 1)
    }
    
    func prepareBuffer() -> AVAudioPCMBuffer {
        let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: bufferCapacity)!
        fillBuffer(buffer)
        return buffer
    }
    
    
    func fillBuffer(_ buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) {
        let data = buffer.floatChannelData?[0]
        let numberFrames = buffer.frameCapacity
        var theta = self.theta
        let theta_increment = 2.0 * .pi * self.frequency / self.sampleRate
        
        for frame in 0..<Int(numberFrames) {
            data?[frame] = Float32(sin(theta) * amplitude)
            
            theta += theta_increment
            if theta > 2.0 * .pi {
                theta -= 2.0 * .pi
            }
        }
        buffer.frameLength = numberFrames
        self.theta = theta
    }
    
    func scheduleBuffer() {
        let buffer = prepareBuffer()
        self.scheduleBuffer(buffer) {
            if self.isPlaying {
                self.scheduleBuffer()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func preparePlaying() {
        scheduleBuffer()
        scheduleBuffer()
        scheduleBuffer()
        scheduleBuffer()
    }
}
```

I successfully generated sounds but I need to hear this sound at different decibel levels, and need to know how to do that? Actually, I am new to this audio buffering, it will be a great help to my project if I got an answer for this.

Is there any way to increase the decibel level of the buffered audio ?

Comment: Increase `amplitude`?

Comment: No, I need to increase the decibel

Comment: Increasing the amplitude will increase decibel (up to the point where the amplitude maxes out the valid range). What else do you want? Do you want to change the volume of the speakers to increase decibel?

Comment: Or do you want to increase the signal-to-noise ratio?

Comment: for example, in my project, there are 5 options to select different decibel level like 20, 30,40,50 etc I need to play the volumes in that volume.

Comment: On macOS, you can control the volume with `AVPlayer.volume` (though you can't specify a specific dB value). On iOS, only the user can change the volume.

Comment: Is there any way to know the decibel of the sound?

Comment: macOS could potentially know the dB level for internal loudspeaker but external loudspeakers are completely out of control for the software. Often they have separate volume control. You probably have to measure and calibrate it yourself.

Comment: Ok, Is there any way to do it? I am actually new to this in swift

Comment: You would need to play a reference song and measure it with separate hardware (a sound level meter, possibly an app providing such functionality). Then you can establish a relationship between the PCM amplitude and the sound level). This needs to be repeated for each loudspeaker and each time the volume of the loudspeaker is changed. This is quite complex, and the complexity is not related to Swift.